# Voting System, database connections?

Tags: posts, database, rating

Basically I'm trying to make it so that all pending posts can be voted on if the user is logged in. once it gets to 10+ votes it will become published.

OK so no longer using database connections and now using Meta Keys, therefore the code has been changed to show what I now have

```
<?php 
//if the post is pending show
if(get_post_status() == 'pending') {

//added a post_vote to the wp_posts database for use later

//if the user is logged in show
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_vote', '0', true );
    $post_vote = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_vote' );
    echo 'Votes: ' .  print_r( $post_vote);
    //form for submit button
    echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"";
    echo '';  //code in here for adding 1 to meta
    echo "\">";
    echo '<input type="button" name="submit" value="+">';
    echo '</form>';

} else {
    echo'Please Sign in to Vote';
}

} else {
// do nothing
}
 ?>
```

The following

```
    add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_vote', '0', true );
    $post_vote = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_vote' );
    echo 'Votes: ' .  print_r( $post_vote);
```

Returns this `Array ( [0] => 0 ) Votes: 1`.

It should only say `Votes: 0`

Comment: "it was awkward to layout on this for some reason" -- my guess, mixture of tabs and spaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want are post meta/custom fields, using these functions:

- `get_post_meta`
- `add_post_meta`
- `update_post_meta`

Adding a new column to the posts table will only cause further issues down the line e.g.:

- database schema changes in WP Core destroying your extra column
- having to write your own custom SQL for everything related to post votes
- No help from WP_Query, object caches, and caching plugins
- No import/export support
- All post types will have the voting column, do you need voting data on attachments, post revisions, and pages?

E.g.

```
update_post_meta(76, 'my_key', 'Steve');
```

Will update/save a 'my_key' meta value of 'steve' to post 76, which we can then retrieve later on using:

```
echo get_post_meta( 76, 'my_key', true );
```

There is a similar meta API for users and comments

Comment: Ah I'll remove that database field then asap and research into the post meta's. Can meta's be integers so I can do a ++ to add onto it or will I need to do elseif 9 times? and Cheers btw.

Comment: meta will be a string, but you can change it type to integer $myvar = intval($myvar)

Comment: Ok, so I'm using the code above (going to edit the post in a moment) and it returns this "Array ( [0] => 0 ) Votes: 1"

Comment: `echo get_post_meta( 76, 'my_key', true );` will give you the value. Without `true`, it will return an array that is what you get now. I have edited the answer. It will reflect once accepted.

Comment: I've made the edit, sorry about that